# How to name base classes so that it's most convenient for those extending a framework?

Tags: naming, inheritance

I'm designing a game engine that is supposed to be overridden. I have, for example, a class called `Character`. Should I prefix this with `BaseCharacter` or should I expect that whoever uses the framework prefixes their classes with `GameNameCharacter` or `CharacterGameName`?

What would be most convenient to you?

Comment: `CharacterBase`

Answer (score 4):

No, just use the simplest name that makes the role of the class obvious in the context of your framework. You don't have to bother with such “smurf naming”, or adding words like “Base”, “Abstract”, “Impl”, …

If a user of your API wants to use the same name as the name of the class in your API, they can import your class under an alias.

The exception here is Java, since Java does not offer any mechanism for type aliases or namespace aliases. You can either use the short class name, or its globally unique fully qualified name (which can get rather lengthy). In Java I'd totally add a prefix to the public classes/interfaces of my library to reduce name clashes with user code.

Comment: Hey :). Thanks for answering :). Actually, I'm targeting Java as well. Let's assume my engine has KL as acronym. So, using the `Character` class example I gave above, which is a quite common word, I should rather say `KLCharacter`, so that anybody using my framework can create their own `Character` based on `KLCharcter`.

Comment: Additionally: even if the target language offers aliasing functionality, do you consider it is tidy to ask of users to use such features? Just trying to see what's best to do :). Won't it be cleaner to name my base classes properly so that the end-users aren't affected regardless of language?

Comment: @Axonn KLCharacter would be fine in Java, I'd argue. But please avoid such names otherwise. E.g. in Python it's completely normal to use a namespace alias `import full.name.of.the.library as kl` so that the class can be named as `kl.Character`.  It's then unnecessary and even unhelpful to add a prefix to the name itself.